# goToNext Animation

Tags: jquery, animation, anchor, smooth-scrolling

I'm creating a link that navigates anchors, but would like to add animation to the scroll

ie... `1000,'easeInOutExpo'`

but can't seem to figure out how to get it working.

Here is the original code for it:

```
<a href="#" onclick="goToNext();return false;">===></a>


<script>
    var max = 5;

    function goToNext() {
        var hash = String(document.location.hash);
        if (hash && hash.indexOf(/box/)) {
            var newh = Number(hash.replace("#box",""));
            (newh > max-1) ? newh = 0 : void(null);
            document.location.hash = "#box" + String(newh+1); 
        } else {
            document.location.hash = "box1";        
        }
    }
</script>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For animating the scroll try -

http://www.sycha.com/jquery-smooth-scrolling-internal-anchor-links

UPDATE:

Try this...

```
<a href="#" onclick="goToNext();return false;">===></a>


<script>
    var max = 5;

    function goToNext() {
        var hash = String(document.location.hash);
        if (hash && hash.indexOf(/box/)) {
            var newh = Number(hash.replace("#box",""));
            (newh > max-1) ? newh = 0 : void(null);
            $('html,body').animate({scrollTop:$("#box" + String(newh+1)).offset().top}, 500);
        } else {
            $('html,body').animate({scrollTop:$("#box1").offset().top}, 500);
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the link, I've actually tried to add that but I'm still a newbie and just having trouble implementing the code into the original. Any help on that would be awesome. Thanks again.

Comment: Is the goToNext function working, and you just want to add animation now?

Comment: Yes, the goToNext function is working and I'm just trying to add the animation.

Comment: Thank you so very much for your help on this. I truly appreciate it. The animation is working (but seems to get stuck on box1 and won't move again). I'm sure I can figure it out from here, unless you have a quick fix. Thanks again for all your help.

Comment: Use F12 and Console.Log(hash) in goToNext to pinpoint the issue.  It's probably not returning the hash you expect.